# Does Apache kylin support taking data for a cube from more than 1 hadoop cluster?

Tags: apache, kylin

I want to take data from hive tables that are in two different clusters , How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Apache KYLIN runs on top of Spark SQL and Spark SQL runs on top of Hive and Hive runs on top of YARN.

I think for kylin it is not possible to take data from multiple clusters.

How ever you can use tools like sqoop to fetch data in one cluster. then you can use KYLIN on all data.